# how to insert data from one table to another table using type in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
   CURSOR c
   IS
      SELECT EMP_ID,      
                     EMP_NAME,    
                     EMAIL,       
                     PHONE_NUMBER,
                     HIRE_DATE,   
                     JOB_ID,
                     Sal from emp;
 TYPE emp_type IS TABLE OF emp%ROWTYPE
   INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

   emp_rec   emp_type;
BEGIN
   OPEN c;

   FETCH c
   BULK COLLECT INTO emp_rec;
   
   If c%Found Then 
   INSERT INTO EMP_NEW
              (EMP_ID,
               EMP_NAME,
               EMAIL,            
               PHONE_NUMBER,      
               HIRE_DATE,         
               JOB_ID,            
               SAL)
SELECT EMP_ID, EMP_NAME, EMAIL,PHONE_NUMBER,HIRE_DATE,JOB_ID, SAL FROM emp_rec ;

   CLOSE c;
END IF;
end;
/
```

here is my above procedure. where im not able to get the data from previous table(emp) to new table (emp_new). it is showing error like table or view not exists. below is the table both follows same structure.

```
CREATE TABLE EMP
(
    EMP_ID          NUMBER (6),
    EMP_NAME        VARCHAR2 (46 BYTE),
    EMAIL           VARCHAR2 (25 BYTE) NOT NULL,
    PHONE_NUMBER    VARCHAR2 (20 BYTE),
    HIRE_DATE       DATE NOT NULL,
    JOB_ID          VARCHAR2 (10 BYTE) NOT NULL,
    SAL             NUMBER (8, 2)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the intention or requirement is to use BULK COLLECT; please try the below:

```
    DECLARE
   TYPE t_bulk_collect_emp_tab IS TABLE OF emp%ROWTYPE;

   l_tab   t_bulk_collect_emp_tab := t_bulk_collect_emp_tab ();
BEGIN
   SELECT *
     BULK COLLECT INTO l_tab
     FROM emp;

   FORALL i IN l_tab.FIRST .. l_tab.LAST
      INSERT INTO emp_new
           VALUES l_tab (i);


   COMMIT;
END;
/
```

E.g. with selected attributes

```
DECLARE
   TYPE t_bulk_collect_emp_tab IS TABLE OF emp%ROWTYPE;

   l_tab   t_bulk_collect_emp_tab := t_bulk_collect_emp_tab ();
BEGIN
   SELECT *
     BULK COLLECT INTO l_tab
     FROM emp;

   FORALL i IN l_tab.FIRST .. l_tab.LAST
      INSERT INTO emp_new (empno, ename)
           VALUES (l_tab (i).empno, l_tab (i).ename);


   COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Comment: it is showing not enough values

Comment: @deepikakumaran Modify the insert statement as per your requirement.

Comment: @deepikakumaran Modified answer with selected attributes.